Explicit generic or dense orbits for the geodesic flow on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$
It is well known that the geodesic flow on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is ergodic.
I am interested in finding as many explicit examples as possible of points $x\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})/SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ such that:

$x$ is generic, that is, its orbit equidistributes.
the orbit of $x$ is dense. Of course every generic point has a dense orbit, but I thought it might be possible to find a larger collection of points whose orbits are only dense.

I can imagine that finding such points would involve some form of symbolic coding, but I don't know how to do it and did not see it anywhere.

I suggest that you post this question in math overflow. It's more likely that you get a good answer there.

You should learn about Artin encoding. Once you learn, you can write as many dense examples as you wish using continued fractions.

@GSofer: It's fine here as well.
